# Vue js retrive new data after ajax call

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have one button when I click on this button I retrive data. But when I click second way I dont retrive new data

Here is my code

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/weobMP

Html

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success form-control" id="click">Filter</button>

<div class="col-md-6 cart-items" id="myjp">
   <div v-for="(item, index) in items">     
      <div class="panel panel-info">
          <div class="panel-heading" v-on:click="greet">
              <h3 {{index+1}} {{item.Car}}</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="mojbody panel-body" v-for="tire in item.tires">
                    Tire: {{tire.Name}}
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
  var id = 1;
$("#click").click(function(){
        id++;
        new Vue({
            el: '#myjp',
        data: {
            items: null
        },
        created: function () {
            this.fetchData();                     
        },
        methods: {
            fetchData: function () {
            var self = this;
            $.get('/retriveHistory',{id: id}, function( data ) {
                self.items = data;
                console.log(data);
            });
            },            
        }
        });       
    })   
  });
```

Comment: You are doing it wrong man. Your are mixing everything, using jQuery events and creating Vue objects from those events. I recommend you to do a Vue course or something. This one is free and really good https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step

Comment: Ok thank you :) But do you know how to solve this problem. Easy way for rebinding data....

Comment: You won't be able to keep rebinding on each click, instead you need to bind your click event to a method in your view model. I would also suggest dumping jQuery completely if you're just starting out with Vue (you can use [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) for ajax calls) which will force you to do things in a coherent way, rather than trying to hack the things you know together. You can then ask here for anything you don't understand.

Comment: I am solved problem only 1 instance can be used